# Smooth invariance of domain

Tags: differential-geometry

This is Theorem 22.3 in Tu's textbook. There are a multiple of similar questions, but all answers seemed unsatisfactory for me. (One of them used algebraic topology result, but I am unfamiliar with the subject.)

Theorem: Let $U$ be an open subset, $S \subset \mathbb R^n$ an arbitrary, and $f: U \rightarrow S$ a diffeomorphism. Then $S$ is open in $\mathbb R^n$.

Proof: Let $f(p)$ be an arbitrary point in $S$ with $p \in U$. **Since $f$ is a diffeomorphism, there is an open set $V \subset \mathbb R^n$ containing $S$ and a smooth map $g: V \rightarrow \mathbb R^n$ such that $g|_S = f^{-1}$**.

I am not sure why the bolded statement is true. I agree that $f(U) \subset S$ is open in $S$, but why does it guarantee the existence of such $g$? If $S$ were a closed set, I may extend $f^{-1}: S \rightarrow U$ to $\tilde g: V \supset S \rightarrow U$ with $\tilde{g}|_S = f^{-1}$ using partition of unity, but there is no assumption about $S$.

Comment: What's the definition of diffeomorphism in the book?

Comment: @FormulaWriter A function $f: M \rightarrow N$ is smooth if $\forall p \in M$ there exists a local chart $(U, \phi)$ about $p$ and a local chart $(V, \psi)$ about $f(p)$ with $f(U) \subset V$. $f$ is smooth if $\psi \circ f \circ \phi^{-1}$ is smooth. $f: M \rightarrow N$ is a local diffeomorphism if two charts above are invertible (by shrinking $U$ and $V$ if necessary). Diffeomorphism just means that $f$ is a global diffeomorphism.

Comment: Edit: in local diffeomorphism, in addition to the fact that $f: M \rightarrow N$ is intertible, smoothness of the inverse is imposed.

Comment: $f(U) \subset S$ is open in $S$, so there is some $V \subset \mathbb R^n$ such that $V \cap S = f(U)$. Also, $f^{-1}: f(U) \rightarrow U$ is a smooth map. However, I am still not sure why $f^{-1}$ can be extended to this smooth $g: V \rightarrow U$ with $g|_S = f^{-1}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a comment but its to long for a comment.
You have to ask yourself what does it mean for a function to be smooth for arbitrary sets of $\mathbb{R}^n$? one possible definition given in the appendix of Lee introduction to smooth manifolds goes as follows

We sometimes need to consider smoothness of functions whose domains are subsets of
$\mathbb{R}^{n}$ that are not open. If $A \subseteq \mathbb{R}^{n}$ is an arbitrary subset, a function $F: A \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{m}$ is said to be smooth on $A$ if it admits a smooth extension to an open neighborhood of each point, or more precisely, if for every $x \in A,$ there exist an open subset $U_{x} \subseteq \mathbb{R}^{n}$ containing $x$ and a smooth function $\widetilde{F}: U_{x} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{m}$ that agrees with $F$ on $U_{x} \cap A .$ The notion of diffeomorphism extends to arbitrary subsets in the obvious way: given arbitrary subsets $A, B \subseteq \mathbb{R}^{n},$ a diffeomorphism from $A$ to $B$ is a smooth bijective map $f: A \rightarrow B$ with smooth inverse.

You can use partition of unity to construct $g$